# How to test willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:?

Tags: ios

I've implemented willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: which performs checks based on the protocol, host and port.

However how can I test this. Couldn't get Charles to do re-directs that are reflected back on the iPhone.
Is there any easy way or tool to simulate i.e. a man-in-the-middle etc. type scenario and test my code doesn't authenticate correctly>

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:
[http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic/](http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic) or http://browserspy.dk/password.php to test your

If you do not authenticate correctly, then you wouldn't get access to the page you are requesting.